# Vertically center background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-image

I am trying to vertically center my background in a div.
I made a schema for a better comprehension:

This is what i have for now :

[image]

The only problem as you can see, is that the image is taller than the div.

I don't want to resize the image, but just want to the image to be centered within the div.

I have made a second image to explain :
[image]

I tried `vertical-align:center` but it didn't work either.

I can't post the jsfiddle because i havn't the reputation to post more than two link... I post it on the comment.

Comment: the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gRtrX/29/

Comment: try doing this (background-attachment : absolute;)

Comment: It's really not easy to understand what you are trying to do in that fiddle. Perhaps describe what you are aiming for in the fiddle in place of the Lorem ipsum.

Comment: @ralph.m in the center of the image there is some colored figure. The image is not center, i just see the top of the image not the center like i want. EDIT : i have the answer :) http://jsfiddle.net/gRtrX/31/

Comment: @ShashankSharma thx, this what i want ! Maybe you can post this a an answer, i can accept and close the post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this `background-attachment : absolute;`

OR

Simply remove this code `background-attachment : fixed;`

Comment: `absolute` is not a value for `background-attachment`. So adding this is the same as doing nothing, because the browser will ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a css property named **background-position**.
background-position takes a x and y value so if you set your background position in your case to 0% 50%. This will move the background position 0% to the right and 50% down (center).

```
background-position:0 50%;
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/joopmicroop/eCm2J/2/)

While you are at it also take a look at **background-size**, background-size has some handy properties 'cover', 'contain'.

**cover**

*Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area.*

**contain**

*Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area*

Together with background-positition you can manage your background sizing and positioning according to the div pretty well.